# How to implement socks5 and socks4 proxies in a single dictionary for requests in python

Tags: python, python-requests, socks

I have socks4 and socks5 list of proxies and I want to use them to scrape a website using python requests.
Requests module supporting both socks5 and socks4 but the problem is I am not able to use both of them at a time as python dictionary not supports duplicate keys like

```
proxies = dict(https='socks4://host:port', https='socks5://host:port')
```

How to get rid off this issue and implement the usage of both proxies with python requests [without need of pysocks]

Comment: `requests` module **does not** support socks proxy by itself, you need to install one more module, check [official docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#socks). And it's not clear what do you want to achieve, using both socks4 and socks5 proxies for what? Are you looking for automatic detection socks proxy version?

Comment: I installed requests[socks] already. Yeah I need automatic detection of socks version like http,ftp,https in requests. proxies = {
    'https': 'socks4://user:pass@host:port',
    'https': 'socks5://user:pass@host:port'
} like this

Comment: Seems like you don't really understand what does socks version means. In `proxies` dictionary each key mean protocol for which this proxy will be used. Format of proxy is: `[PROTOCOL]:://{[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@}[HOST]:[PORT]`, so protocol which proxy uses you specify in proxy string. Socks4 and Socks5 are not the same, so you should know socks version.

Comment: Sir I know socks4 and socks5 proxies are different and btw the proxies I am using don’t need any authentication . I want to use both socks4 and socks5 proxies But I am not able to add both in a single dictionary . It won’t works if we give proxies like  proxies = { “socks4” : “socks4://proxy:Port”} .. it working only when I give proxies = {“https”:”socks4://proxy:port”} and proxies = {“https”:”socks5://proxy:port”} . Here I can’t be able to add both socks4 and socks5 in the proxies dictionary as the key for both is same. I hope you understand the exact problem I have (:

Comment: What result are you expecting from using both socks4 and socks5 proxies? It sounds absurd for now, probably I'm missing smth.

Comment: Scraping the data from the website through multiple requests

Comment: Why do you need several proxies for that?

Comment: Because the website is banning the ip after few requests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221165/discussion-between-lakshmipathi-and-olvin-roght).

Comment: Great, but how does using 2 different version of socks would help? You need to replace proxy if you get banned.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Kindly check the message in the chat :)